# How to add a full image in excel using filecontent in power automate

Tags: typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

I have a microsoft forms that let user answer some questions and upload a picture. All the response will be saved into an excel table with power automate flow. Those answers will be save as string, URL point to OneDrive for the picture will be saved into excel table too.

Ok, many have ask the question on how to insert the picture into excel using that URL but so far no solution on that. The standard answer from Microsoft seems not working -- there is fetch error whenever the URL is point to OneDrive / SharePoint (Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/add-image-to-workbook))

I'm asking the same question from another aspect. I can get the filecontent in power automate flow. When I download the file content and inspect it, it have the data structures like this (this is not full file content for security reason):

> {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Pragma":"no-cache","x-ms-request-id":"0f368276-7f62-4daa-82a7-98f5fda","Timing-Allow-Origin":"*","x-ms-apihub-cached-response":"false","Accept-Ranges":"bytes","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Date":"Mon, 11 Oct 2021 09:21:21 GMT","ETag":""{D2E67548-99EE-4BA3-BAB3},4"","Location":"https://flow-apim-msmanaged-na-centralus-01.azure-apim.net/apim/onedriveforbusiness/a47f3c2699aa4df70f3614572a9/datasets/default/files/01YEFL272IOXTNF.../content?inferContentType=true","X-AspNet-Version":"4.0.30319","X-Powered-By":"ASP.NET","Content-Length":"137453","Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename="16337833927412488499783584031011.jpg"","Content-Type":"image/jpeg","Expires":"-1"},"body":{"$content-type":"image/jpeg","$content":"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...==}}

From what I can tell, strings after "body":{"$content-type":"image/jpeg","$content":, starting from /9j/4UVORX until ...== is the base64 string for that image which logically could be pass to an OfficeScript and call worksheet.AddImage API to insert full picture into excel worksheet as image directly.

Anyone have any idea on how to extract the base64 string using OfficeScript if I pass the filecontent from power automate flow to OfficeScript?

===Add-on===

After some reseach, I manage to extract the correct string out of file content using json function:

```
json(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body']?['$content'])
```

[image]

However, it prompt for error: Action 'Compose' failed...

[image]

Argh... running out of idea ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This flow worked for me:
[image: A Power Automate flow to insert an image uploaded from Form into Excel]

The `Content` expression in the `Parse JSON` action is something like this:

```js
first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r926aef8d3cf24b569e10513f3d540e0a']))
```

It is to get the information of the file uploaded with the form. The actual expression might be different based on your form. You only need to insert the correct form response field into `first(json(  ))`:
[image: Parse JSON expression]

The `Schema` used in the `Parse JSON` action is:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "link": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {},
        "size": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "referenceId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "driveId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "uploadSessionUrl": {}
    }
}
```

And the `base64ImageString` expression used to pass into the `Run script` action is:

```js
base64(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body'])
```

Finally, if you are interested in the script I have used here:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, sheetName: string, address: string, base64ImageString: string) {
  let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName);
  let range = sheet.getRange(address);
  let image = sheet.addImage(base64ImageString);
  image.setTop(range.getTop());
  image.setLeft(range.getLeft());
}
```